# Create SQL Pivot Table Depending On Different Periods of times

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I want to create pivot table for data of the due values of different customers, and i want to pivot my data to 3 pivoted periods of time Such that the first Column has the total notes of the period from today till 30 days from now in the future and the second one for the values due in the period of ((Now + 30)< Due <60)
and the next one has values of ((Now+ 60) < Due < 90) and the last one has the value due today.
This's My Code which get my raw data:

```
SELECT [ADD].AccountID
      ,SUM(convert(money,ADDN.Amount - ISNULL(CollectedValue,0))) AS [Total Rest Amount]
      ,ADDN.DueDate  AS [Due Date]
FROM [Accounting].[AccDocumentDetailsNotes] ADDN
INNER JOIN Accounting.AccDocumentDetails [ADD]
ON   ADDN.AccDocumentDetailID = [ADD].ID
INNER JOIN Accounting.AccDocumentHeader ADH
ON ADH.ID = [ADD].AccDocumentHeaderID
INNER JOIN [Accounting].[AccNotesCollectors] ANC
ON  ANC.NoteID = ADDN.ID
INNER JOIN Accounting.AccAccounts AA
ON AA.ID = [ADD].AccountID
GROUP BY [ADD].AccountID,ADDN.DueDate,[CodeTypePart],ADDN.Amount,CollectedValue
HAVING  [CodeTypePart] = 'NR' AND convert(money,ADDN.Amount - ISNULL(CollectedValue,0)) > 0
```

And This's a Historical sample from the result:

```
AccountID   Total Rest Amount     Due Date
----------- --------------------- -----------------------
25          6800.00               2017-02-23 17:31:09.000
25          1700.00               2017-02-23 17:31:09.000
25          10602.00              2017-05-28 16:28:14.000
27          14500.00              2017-02-28 14:53:57.000
30          120150.00             2017-02-24 00:23:20.000
30          117050.00             2017-02-24 00:23:20.000
33          2000.00               2017-04-04 20:48:51.193
45          39500.00              2017-04-18 20:13:46.000
45          31300.00              2017-04-18 20:13:46.000
45          9000.00               2017-04-18 20:13:46.000
45          32200.00              2017-04-22 16:38:47.803
46          32500.00              2017-02-23 20:14:24.000
46          15910.00              2017-02-23 20:14:24.000
```

And I want to seems as:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to break down your data into groups by how overdue it is, and then pivot on that. Then to get the total, you can add together all the sub-columns.

```
select 
    AccountID,
    isnull([90+],0)+isnull( [today 61-90],0)+ isnull( [today 31-60],0)+isnull( [today-30],0) total,
    [90+], [today 61-90], [today 31-60], [today-30]  

from
(
    select AccountId, Amount, 
        CASE 
            WHEN datediff(d, duedate, getdate()) <= 30 THEN 'today-30'
            when datediff(d, duedate, getdate()) between 31 and 60 then 'today 31-60'
            when datediff(d, duedate, getdate()) between 61 and 90 then 'today 61-90'
            else '90+'
        END as daysoverdue

     from @t    
) src
pivot
( sum(Amount) for daysoverdue in ([90+], [today 61-90], [today 31-60], [today-30]  ))p
```

Comment: These answers will change minute by minute because you are doing the date arithmetic as DateTimes instead of as Dates. That is not how accounting or bookkeeping actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with data as (
    select
        Today     = cast(getdate() as date),
        Plus30    = dateadd(d, 30, cast(getdate() as date) ),
        Plus60    = dateadd(d, 60, cast(getdate() as date) ),
        Plus90    = dateadd(d, 90, cast(getdate() as date) ),
        EndOfTime = cast('21991231' as date),
        t.*
    from @t as t
)
select
    AccountId,
    Total      = sum(Amount),
    Due0To30   = sum(pvt.Due0To30),
    Due31To60  = sum(pvt.Due31To60),
    Due61To90  = sum(pvt.Due61To90),
    Due91Plus  = sum(pvt.Due91Plus)
from data
cross apply (values
    (Today,  Plus30,    Amount, 0, 0, 0),
    (Plus30, Plus60,    0, Amount, 0, 0),
    (Plus60, Plus90,    0, 0, Amount, 0),
    (Plus90, EndOfTime, 0, 0, 0, Amount)
)pvt(StartDate,EndDate,Due0To30, Due31To60, Due61To90, Due91Plus)
where [Due Date] >= pvt.StartDate
  and [Due Date] <  pvt.EndDate
group by AccountID
```